# How to structure Django models for pages and rich text

Tags: python, django, database, database-schema

I am working on a Django app and I'm having some issues with the structuring of my models.

What I have is 3 models Topic, Video, and Document, and the video and document models are in many to many relationship with the Topic model, like so:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
     name = models.Charfield(max_length=20)
     videos = models.manytomanyfield('Video', blank=True)
     docs = models.manytomanyfield('Document', blank=True)

class Video(models.Model):
     title = models.Charfield(max_length=20)
     videourl = models.Charfield()


class Document(models.Model):
     title = models.Charfield(max_length=20)
     doc = models.Textfield()
```

So I'm having two problems;

-First, I want to have the document Model to be a rich text document, like in Google Docs where a user on the site can write a document and put images in the document. How do I create a model that can support this?

-Second, I want to have multiple Video and Document objects for each Topic object and have each Video and Document have there own page and have those pages have a specific order (ie. video1, video2, document1, video3, document4, etc...). How can I keep track of what page number each document or video is?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

By reading your question I can be sure you don't have the knowledge or skills to create even a simple app, so just take it easy. Also, read the rules of how to write a question

First: You already have TextField(), it will be enough for you, believe me.

Second: Read Django documentation  about models or watch any tutorials, and don't ask questions if you didn't even look for it